# Mac system application extension

Tags: macos, code-injection

I'm trying to modify the functionality of mission control which belongs to dock.app and I'm wondering what the preferred method of doing so would be. I've looked into using the simpler method of defaults but that won't give me enough control. I'm curious if people use something like Application Enhancer by Unsanity to execute custom code for these purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Application Enhancer is effectively a dead project at this point -- while the current version does advertise support for Lion, Mountain Lion is slated for release within the next month, and it is unlikely that they will ever support it (as neither the Unsanity site nor their Twitter account has not been updated at all since last November). I would recommend strongly against using it for new products.

Under previous releases of OS X, SIMBL and PlugSuit have been popular, but neither one is available on Lion. The options seem to be more limited now; however, Rentzch's [mach_star](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star) (mach_override / mach_inject) code seems to still be working.